# Hidden Menu clicked, trigger main menu active states Joomla

Tags: joomla, menu, hidden

I've ask this question on Joomla Official Forums-http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=862922&f=706

But no one is able to help.

---

I need some help, I'm new to Joomla, I've created a website for my friend- http://www.maverikswarehouse.com
I'm stuck on the menus active states
I'm using FavouriteDark theme

I've created a Hidden Menu, these have category blogs in them, how do I make the Main Menu items in active state while one of the posts in hidden menu is clicked?

For example- I click on Gallery, then i click on one of the items, it will redirect to an article post, but the Gallery Menu is no longer active. How do I make it active?

Comment: Please ask your question on the dedicated [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) site ;)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have the hidden menu items as submenu-items of your visible menus. Like this:

Mainmenu:

```
Gallery
    Item 1
    Item 2
Other
Menu
Items
...
```

Now, if you go to Item 1, Gallery will get the class=active, and you can use this to style it. So now all you have to do is make sure leve2 two of your menu is not displayed. This can be done in many ways, the easiest to configure this in the module, where you can set which levels should display. If this does not work for you, you can hide individual items setting display:none on each item you want to hide.